# Text Field on a MacOS Cocoa program turns black during certain operations

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, textfield

I have a simple Mac program I write in Xcode/Cocoa that works fine on my Mac(Yosemite), but on another Mac(El Capitan) some (all?) Text Field's turn black under some circumstances.  I don't know if it is OS Version, or some other color or theme preference the user has on that computer.  But looking for ideas what to look for.

a) Busy processing - short burst of read/write from a USB device - sometimes the color wheel shows during this processing.  When complete however, the Text Fields go to back to normal foreground and background.
b) App loses focus - click outside my app, like the desktop, where my app loses "focus".  When my app does not have focus, the Text Fields are blank.  But if I click back into my app, the fields go back to normal foreground and background colors.

[image: "Normal" field color appearance]

[image: "Black" field color appearance]

Comment: are these NSTextFields or are they *subclassed* NSTextFields?

Comment: Plain old NSTextFIelds.  Dropped them on the form, no subclassing.